# Having trouble to understand a portion of regex

Tags: regex, unix, sed

This is the text:

```
We will now present the Linux ls command
   ... here description of ls

We will now present the Linux cd command
   ... here description of cd
   ... more description
Done
```

This following sed replacement regex is applied on the text

```
sed 's/.*Linux \(.*\) .*/\1:/' ex2.txt
```

Which gives the following output

```
ls:
   ... here description of ls

cd:
   ... here description of cd
   ... more description
Done
```

Can someone please walk me through on how it worked?

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ and http://regexr.com/ are your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*Linux` : Anything before the word “Linux” and that word itself followed by a space. (**`We will now present the Linux`** )

`\(.*\)`: Then something captured with parentheses. (**`ls`** or **`cd`**)

`.*`: Then another space and anything else. ( **`command`**)

---

Replaced by:

`\1:`: Whatever the first capturing group has captured, followed by a colon (**`ls:`** or **`cd:`**)

---

In this case, `.` matches any character *except line breaks*.

`\(.*\)` matches only that one word because there has to be a space before “Linux” and there has to be a space after that word: the space between the command name and the word “command”.

The parentheses don’t have to be escaped with a backslash if extended regex is used (`sed -r`…).

So you could also write:

```bash
sed -r 's/.*Linux (.*) .*/\1:/' ex2.txt
```